# 'Chart' TargetType does not match type of element 'Chart'

Tags: charts, visifire

Using Visifire Charts the XAML-Designer instead of showing me the chart shows a InvalidOperationException: 
***'Chart' TargetType does not match type of element 'Chart'.***
 When running the application the chart gets shown correctly. 
 Has anybody made the same experience and solved the issue? If yes, how?