# CustomButton_123509716 targetType does not match type of element CustomButton_096728

Tags: xaml, styles, visual-studio-2017, design-time

I recently switched to Visual Studio 2017, and my xaml design time view has suffered considerably.

The most recent challenge is a design time-only bug where my components won't show up because their **style_1093579** doesn't match **style_0965327**, but when I run the program, it works fine.

I agree that the numbers don't match, but I didn't add them, and can't figure out how to update them.  I have tried cleaning, resetting, reverting, and manually deleting files. I've attached to the process to try to debug it. I've added *[DesignTimeVisible(true)]* to see if that would change anything - all I've managed to do is get some of the numbers to change. I've Googled, but even the promising questions, like [TargetType does not match type of Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804752/targettype-does-not-match-type-of-element) or ['Chart' TargetType does not match type of element 'Chart'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252525/chart-targettype-does-not-match-type-of-element-chart) either don't apply, or are not answered.

My best guess is that some auto generated file does not get regenerated correctly when I rebuild. (it's not the *.g.i.cs file though - I already tried deleting it.) Does anyone have another file I should try deleting, or a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem when creating a view based on my custom `ContentControl`, where I had created a Style for my custom `ContentControl`.

Try to explicitly set the TargetType of the Style on the `CustomButton` to the one used on the element that the Style is defined with.

So in in a view that is based on your `CustomButton`

```
<my:CustomButton x:Class="MyModule.Views.MyButtonView">
    <my:CustomButton.Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleCustomButton}" TargetType="{x:Type my:CustomButton}" />
    </my:CustomButton.Style>
</my:CustomButton>
```

when `StyleCustomButton` is defined similar to this:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleCustomButton"
       TargetType="{x:Type my:CustomButton}">
...
```